# Как сохранить запись (CKRecord), а именно изображение из UIImageView в iCloud?

Tags: swift, imageview, облако, save, record

`import CloudKit`

Как сохранить запись `CKRecord`, а именно изображение из `UIImageView` в iCloud?

Comment: Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив ответа)

Answer (score 0):

ну примерно так (если вы знаете имя файла):

```
let urlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myImage", ofType: "jpg") //Получаем путь к файлу

let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: urlpath!) //инитим урл пути

let imageForSave = CKAsset.init(fileURL: url) //создаем ассет для того что бы положить его в запись

let record = CKRecord.init(recordType: "myImageRecordName") //создаем запись с типом по вашему вкусу

record.setObject(imageForSave, forKey: "image") //сетапим нашу картинку к записи

let database = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase // тут нужно выбрать тип базы куда будем сохранять

database.save(record) { (savedRecord, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!) // если ошибка то выводим ну и т.д.

        // можно попробовать тут
        let recordOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation.init(recordsToSave: [record], recordIDsToDelete: nil) // создаем операцию модификации данных
        recordOperation.savePolicy = .ifServerRecordUnchanged // настраиваем savePolicy
        recordOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (recordsSaved, recordsIDs, error) in
            if error != nil {
                 print(error!) // если ошибка то выводим ну и т.д.
            }
        } // ставим колбек который вызовется после завершения операции

        database.add(recordOperation)

    }
} // сохраняем в базу, но только если там нет такой записиб если есть то метод вернет ошибку и нам нужно использовать CKModifyRecordsOperation
```

ссылки на документацию [CKAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckasset), [CKRecord](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord#2166530), [CKModifyRecordsOperation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckmodifyrecordsoperation)

---

если не знаете имя файла то можно сделать такой хак

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image!)!

let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .picturesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

let imageURL = docDir.appendingPathComponent("imageName.png")

do {
     try imageData.write(to: imageURL)
} catch let error {
     print(error)
}
```